# Spring Boot: Running as a Java application but classpath contains spring-web

Tags: spring-boot

I've successfully managed to create a Spring boot application that runs as a Java application as follows:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SpringApplication springApplication = new SpringApplication();
    springApplication.setWebEnvironment(false);
    springApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}
```

The problem is that my application requires the `spring-web` module as it is a client to a REST service.

Once I add the `spring-web` module I get an error:

```
Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean.
```

How can I get it to run as a Java application with `spring-web` on the classpath

Comment: Did you try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22995527/how-do-i-launch-a-spring-boot-application-without-the-embedded-tomcat ? Should work. Perhaps you need 1.3 for this

Comment: @Marged yes I did, see my snippet above

Comment: Sorry, didn't see the setter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have "same setup" as you - command line spring boot app that uses `RestTemplate` from `spring-web` and everything works well. Maybe it is just that I use "full" spring web starter.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

(and just slightly different main but it shouldn't be a difference)

```
    SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(MyApplication.class);
    app.setWebEnvironment(false);
    app.run(args);
```

Comment: The app.run(args) is the key here, by including my Application.class it was creating a default configuration and ignoring my settings, so by excluding that it now runs as a Java process. Thanks!

Comment: hm, I was not expecting such simple problem -> calling static method in non static way. your had IDE probably warned you about it :) but glad it works now.

Comment: This is not a static method, although there is another static run() method as well, I was not using this.

Comment: in version 1.3.1 SpringApplication has only 3 `run` methods - but only one - `run(String...)` is non-static. but it is just detail :)